# Do I need to lower my CPU voltage when lowering the CPU multiplier?

Tags: cpu, overclocking, underclock

I know that when overclocking you might have to increase the CPU voltage to keep it stable, but is the opposite true for underclocking?

My CPU has a base clock of 100mhz and a default multiplier of 36, which I changed to 26. The PC still works fine, but I'm curious about whether the CPU voltage needs to be lowered to prevent damage too.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you basically trying to avoid over-heating?

Comment: No, I'm just curious to see how lowering the CPU clock speed affects the PCs power consumption. I got myself one of those devices that shows you an appliance's power consumption and since then I got curious about different devices power draws.